# How to Promise.allSettled with Scala futures?

Tags: scala, promise, future

I have two scala futures. I want to perform an action once both are **completed**, regardless of whether they were completed **successfully**. (Additionally, I want the ability to inspect those results at that time.)

In Javascript, this is [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled).

Does Scala offer a simple way to do this?

One last wrinkle, if it matters: I want to do this in a JRuby application.

Comment: Have you look at `Future.sequence` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`transform`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html#transform%5BS%5D(f:scala.util.Try%5BT%5D=%3Escala.util.Try%5BS%5D)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future%5BS%5D) method to create a Future that will always succeed and return the result or the error as a `Try` object.

```scala
def toTry[A](future: Future[A])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Try[A]] =
  future.transform(x => Success(x))
```

To combine two Futures into one, you can use `zip`:

```scala
def settle2[A, B](fa: Future[A], fb: Future[B])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
    : Future[(Try[A], Try[B])] =
  toTry(fa).zip(toTry(fb))
```

If you want to combine an arbitrary number of Futures this way, you can use `Future.traverse`:

```scala
def allSettled[A](futures: List[Future[A]])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
    : Future[List[Try[A]]] = 
  Future.traverse(futures)(toTry(_))
```

Comment: Stacking `Future` and `Try` is overly complicated/engineered

Comment: Honestly, that's just a silly argument to make because `Promise.allSettled` yields an array of objects that are isomorphic to Scala's `Try` type. The `allSettled` method I've written is as close as you're ever going to get to JavaScript's `Promise.allSettled` in idiomatic Scala.

Answer (score 1):

Normally in this case we use `Future.sequence` to transform a collection of a Future into one single Future so you can map on it, but Scala short circuit the failed Future and doesn't wait for anything after that (Scala considers one failure to be a failure for all), which doesn't fit your case.

In this case you need to map failed ones to successful, then do the sequence, e.g.

```
val settledFuture = Future.sequence(List(future1, future2, ...).map(_.recoverWith { case _ => Future.unit }))
settledFuture.map(//Here it is all settled)
```

**EDIT**

Since the results need to be kept, instead of mapping to Future.unit, we map the actual result into another layer of Try:

```
val settledFuture = Future.sequence(
  List(Future(1), Future(throw new Exception))
    .map(_.map(Success(_)).recover(Failure(_)))
  )
settledFuture.map(println(_))
//Output: List(Success(1), Failure(java.lang.Exception))
```

**EDIT2**

It can be further simplified with `transform`:

```
Future.sequence(listOfFutures.map(_.transform(Success(_))))
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution. If you do things this way, you lose the exception which might be relevant later on. You will usually get a result of type `Any`, because that is usually the least upper bound of the futures' result type and `Unit`, and if the futures return Unit, you don't know whether the original future succeeded or failed. On top of that, the OP mentioned that he has two futures, and there's no reason to assume that these are of the same type, so you're again losing type safety. Furthermore, `Future.sequence(foo.map(bar))` better expressed as `Future.traverse(foo)(bar)`.

Comment: @MatthiasBerndt Added solution to keep the result

Comment: You still 
a) lose the result type, b) don't know in the general case if the Future succeeded or failed c) have the `Future.sequence(foo.map(bar))` antipattern and 
d) can't combine Futures of different types while preserving their types (OP explicitly asked about two Futures, not an arbitrary number)

Comment: @MatthiasBerndt Success with a Throwable result is very anti pattern. Also OP did not mention the result type of his Futures should be persisted. We can do pattern matching in Scala to match types anyway. In his reference to JS `Promise.allSettled`, it returns a collection of all results which is exactly what my example does.

Comment: Whether or not using a subtype of `Throwable` as a successful result of a `Future` is an antipattern is besides the point; generic code like this shouldn't make any assumptions about that either way. And pattern matching on non-sealed types (like `Any`) is another terrible idea, because the compiler can't check exhaustiveness and because it doesn't work with generics (e. g. can't tell `List[Int]` and `List[String]` apart).

Comment: By the way, if having a `Future` succeed with a `Throwable` is an antipattern, then I wonder why [this method](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html#failed:scala.concurrent.Future[Throwable]) exists in the `Future` API.

Comment: @MatthiasBerndt if all the Futures have the same result type, you can also wrap it with a monad that can do coproduct for the result and exception, like Try or Either, but OP did not mention this so I didn't consider this a requirement.

Comment: Not throwing type information out of the window is not a matter of requirements but simply good programming practice.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a concurrent counter to keep track of the number of completed `Future`s and then complete the `Promise` once all `Future`s have completed

```
def allSettled[T](futures: List[Future[T]]): Future[List[Future[T]]] = {
  val p = Promise[List[Future[T]]]()
  val length = futures.length
  val completedCount = new AtomicInteger(0)
  futures foreach {
    _.onComplete { _ =>
      if (completedCount.incrementAndGet == length) p.trySuccess(futures)
    }
  }
  p.future
}

val futures = List(
  Future(-11),
  Future(throw new Exception("boom")),
  Future(42)
)

allSettled(futures).andThen(println(_))
// Success(List(Future(Success(-11)), Future(Failure(java.lang.Exception: boom)), Future(Success(42))))
```

[scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BhKXNpbGSEyeqzghV8JgdQ)